# How do I extract excel data from multiple worksheets and put into one sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, database, worksheet-function

In a workbook I have 7 sheets(Totals and then Mon to Sat),I want to extract rows which have the word "CHEQ" in its cell (this is a dropdown list with two options-CHEQ/PAID)from all sheets. On my front sheet I used this formula:

```
=IF(ROWS(A$13:A13)>$C$10,"",INDEX(Monday!A$3:A$62,SMALL(IF(Monday[Paid]=$A$10,ROW(Monday[Paid])-ROW(Monday!$I$3)+1),ROWS(A$13:A13))))
```

This formula works fine for one worksheet (eg. Monday) but is it possible to show the extracted rows from all 6 sheets on the front page? I only have Excel NOT Access. These are the 12 headers on row A12

```
Col Name     Cod  House Car Date  Discount 2nd Paid  Extra Letter Posted
```

The exported data appears like this (this just an example):

```
Col Name     Cod  House Car Date  Discount 2nd Paid  Extra Letter Posted
12  Robbs    1244 Ren         11/10 10%  5   CHEQ  0     0    No
15  Jones    7784 Ren         12/10 15%  1   CHEQ  0     0    No
18  Doese    1184       Ren   12/11 12%  1   CHEQ  0     0    No
```

Any ideas on what to do to this formula? I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: VLOOKUP might be a prospect if you are looking to get "CHEQ" from 6 sheets to a single sheet. (CHEQ would be in the 9th column?). you would have to do this for each sheet from the master sheet.

Comment: what would that look like?could you show me a formula please.

Comment: VLOOKUP will not provide the required result, but I will keep testing and if I find it, I will post answer.

Comment: Would your expected result yeild 6 rows (for Mon thru Sat) of each name on your front page?

Comment: Yes on the front back it would show up.

Comment: oops. Yes on the front page it would show up the results.
cells A15 to K15 and A30 to K30 has the formula I used (shown at the top of this page).
cell A12 has droplist "Paid"/"Cheq".
cell B12 has =COUNTIF(Monday[Paid],A12)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do this by putting a button on the totals page connected to a VBA macro.

In the macro, I would apply the appropriate filter to each details page. Then copy the filtered results to the totals page. You will need, to track the number of rows pasted and set a variable to keep the next free row straight.

Then you can click the button each time you want to update the totals.

Comment: I would but the annoying thing is other staff can't use macros (we are on a system called Cytix) unless I goto everyone's pc and put my macro filled personal.xls file on there excel.so sadly that suggestion isn't possible :( I need to use a macro free answer.